# No Gazebo GUI error with gazebo_ros command

Tags: gazebo, ros2, gazebo-plugin, ros2-launch

[image]

Gazebo GUI didn't work when i used the "ros2 launch gazebo_ros gazebo.launch.py" command, It did appear with the "gazebo" command. Does anyone know how to fix this? I have tried to reinstall gazebo and gazebo_ros pkg for couples of time, but It didnt work.

After running the "ros2 launch gazebo_ros gazebo.launch.py --debug" command, It said: "Failed to load the launch file without a context: ThisLaunchFileDir used outside of a launch file (in a script)"
[image: Debug image]

**Solution: "source /usr/share/gazebo/setup.bash" is required, I dont know why it is required because all tutorial that i watched this source command was not added. After adding this command, My problem is solved.**

Comment: Try running the launch system in debug mode for verbose output. This is done as follows: `ros2 launch gazebo_ros gazebo.launch.py --debug`. If this mode gives more information, please update the question accordingly.

Comment: After running the "ros2 launch gazebo_ros gazebo.launch.py" command, It said: "Failed to load the launch file without a context: ThisLaunchFileDir used outside of a launch file (in a script)". (image above)

Comment: Please copy and paste console output not screenshot. It's much more readable as well as searchable.